# Does getContentPane().add() mean the same as add()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Does getContentPane().add() mean the same as add() ?

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame{
    public TestFrame() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("jo");
        getContentPane().add(label);
        add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: The JFrame API will answer this question quicker than asking it here. :)

Comment: Hi I tried with first the API, but there's was no hint.

Comment: @user268755 if you're in eclipse click on add() and hit shift+f2, then do the same with getContentPane().add() on the add() part - you'll end up at the same point in the API document showing they are the same exact call.

Comment: Indeed I did that, but you don't know if JFrame getContentPane() returns another objects, that's whay I asked it here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does getContentPane().add() mean the same as add() ?

Yes, since 1.5+.

Comment: where's the API reference for this ?

Comment: @user268755: Check the preamble for the [1.4 version of JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) as opposed to the [1.5 version of JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).  Use some Google-fu to find the release notes for 1.5 that support the change.

Comment: thx a lot, I always used a local javadoc version 1.6, thx for the 1.4 hint.

Comment: There's also a helpful [note here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html#contentpane).

Answer (score 3):

Mostly. To make things "easier", `addImpl` was changed to forward to the content pane, but in uncommon corner cases it doesn't (for instance, the content pane needs to be added somehow).

> [This method is overridden to conditionally forward calls to the contentPane.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#addImpl%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because if you notice they both are from

```
Class Container
java.lang.Object
  java.awt.Component
      java.awt.Container
add()
```

JLabel extends container and getContentPane() returns container.