# Why did JFrame originally require getContentPane() for adding components

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I know that, [as of Java 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921442/does-getcontentpane-add-mean-the-same-as-add), one can add a component to a JFrame like this:

> myFrame.add(myButton);

instead of:

> myFrame.getContentPane().add(myButton);

Why wasn't this always the case?

Comment: My reason for asking is I'm teaching Intro CS and the examples in the book all use the old notation.  I'd like to be able to give the students some reason why it was once necessary to do the extra step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As is spelled out in the [JFrame API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), both do the same thing: add a component to the contentPane. It's just recently (Java 1.5 perhaps?) Swing added the syntactic sugar/convenience method to allow you to make this call directly on the JFrame (or any other Swing top-level container), but you're still adding to the contentPane. Same for `remove(...)` and `setLayout(...)` This becomes all too clear if you try to set the background color of the JFrame via `myJFrame.setBackground(Color.green);` and nothing happens. It is for this reason, I'm not too happy with this change. That and also because I must be an old curmudgeon.

Comment: Could you tell me why you're unhappy with the change?  I'm trying to understand the argument against it.

Comment: The concept leads newbies into believing that the JFrame is actually what's getting the component. **Again** try calling setBackground(...) on the JFrame.

Comment: Thanks.  Why not make the JFrame the container in the first place so setBackground() does what people expect?

Comment: @espertus: please read the Swing [tutorial section on JFrames and other top-level windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), especially if you're going to be teaching this stuff. There you'll see why -- that Swing uses a structured  hierarchy of objects when creating JFrames or other top level windows including the JFrame, the JRootPane, the contentPane, the glassPane, etc... each with its own functionality. This is very important stuff and can't really be explained well in a forum, not as well as the tutorial does at any rate.

Comment: I don't think this counts as "syntactical sugar". But +1 for the general idea of hacks to make things simpler ending up making understanding what's going on more difficult.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: sure it is. It is a change in syntax or meaning of syntax that doesn't add any functionality that wasn't there before.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I've started reading through the tutorial.  So far, it seems to be descriptive, rather than saying why top-level windows have a content pane rather than accepting children directly, but I'll keep reading.

Comment: It's a divide and conquer philosophy. The JFrame itself is consentrated with creating a window that must contain native code and be built on native GUI components. All the other components in the top-level window are light weight and each perform their own roles -- the contentPane to hold all of the components added to a GUI and to lay them out, the menu bar to hold the menus, the glasspane to cover all and the root pane to hold them all.

Answer (score 7):

- [Bug ID: 4753342 JFrame, JWindow and JDialog should redirect add/remove methods to ContentPane](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4753342). And more details can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/swing/1.5/index.html#swingMajor). To navigate directly to the item, do a search on the Bug ID.

> **4753342: Swing's top level component should redirect add/remove
> methods to ContentPane 
>
> Description:**
>
> Contrary to AWT programming,
> `JFrame`/`JDialg`/`JWindow`/`JApplet`/`JInternalFrame` do not allow you to add
> `Component`s to it, instead you must learn about `JRootPane` and add
> children `Component`s to it. This adds needless confusion to new
> developers.
>
> Prior to 5.0, attempting to add or remove a `Component` from one of
> these top level `Component`s would result in an exception be thrown. In
> 5.0, no exception will be thrown, instead the `Component` will be added or removed from the content pane. This resulted in several revisions
> to the javadoc of `JFrame`, `JDialog`, `JWindow`, `JApplet` and
> `JInternalFrame`. This has been summarized in RootPaneContainer's
> javadoc:
>
> ```
>  * For conveniance
>  * <code>JFrame</code>, <code>JDialog</code>, <code>JWindow</code>,
>  * <code>JApplet</code> and <code>JInternalFrame</code>, by default,
>  * forward all calls to <code>add</code> and its variants,
>  * <code>remove</code> and <code>setLayout</code> to the
>  * <code>contentPane</code>. This means rather than writing:
>  * <pre>
>  * rootPaneContainer.getContentPane().add(component);
>  * </pre>
>  * you can do:
>  * <pre>
>  * rootPaneContainer.add(component);
>  * </pre>
>  * <p>
>  * The behavior of <code>add</code> and its variants and
>  * <code>setLayout</code> for
>  * <code>JFrame</code>, <code>JDialog</code>, <code>JWindow</code>,
>  * <code>JApplet</code> and <code>JInternalFrame</code> is controlled by
>  * the <code>rootPaneCheckingEnabled</code> property. If this property is
>  * true, the default, then <code>add</code> and its variants and
>  * <code>setLayout</code> are
>  * forwarded to the <code>contentPane</code>, if it is false, then these
>  * methods operate directly on the <code>RootPaneContainer</code>. This
>  * property is only intended for subclasses, and is therefor protected.
> ```

Also, here's a related bug:

- [Bug ID: 6265511 Swing JFrame/JWindow/JApplet/JDialog: getLayout and remove should forward to content pane](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=55a9828182425619f2ad1188ea726?bug_id=6265511)